# COUNT() in SELECT not producing desired output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

usStateCities:
[image: usStateCities]

And  usstatescentroids:
[image: usstatescentroids]

```
SELECT state,COUNT(*) AS  count  FROM usStateCities  GROUP BY state
```

Gives the number of cities in each state

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT state, COUNT(*)  AS count FROM  usstatecities ) AS a,
usstatescentroids b
WHERE a.state = b.state
GROUP BY state
```

Only gives one state and total number of cities in US
I want to find the number of cities in each state and the coordinates (lon,lat) of the centroid of each state.

CORRECTION I have change State to state. I cut and pasted older statements.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: Hv you checked the result of your subquery, is it as per requirment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.state, a.count, b.lon, b.lat 
FROM (SELECT State, COUNT(*) AS count FROM usStateCities GROUP BY State) a
LEFT JOIN usstatescentroids b ON b.state = a.State
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use join table then subquery. try bellow:

```
SELECT b.State, b.lon, b.lat, COUNT(*) AS  count  
FROM usStateCities  a, usstatescentroids b
WHERE a.state = b.state
GROUP BY b.State, b.lon, b.lat
```

Comment: I would advise against using implicit joins. In addition, this query would take longer as it's joining a larger data set.